# ugarchforecast seems to no recognize my external regressors

Tags: python, r, time-series, forecasting, quantitative-finance

I'm new in R and using the rugarch package  with external regressors
Everything seems to work good with the fitting step but  Im struggling with the forecast.
Please see below the piece of code for the fitting and  the forecast
to make it simple there is no ARMA and constant mean in the model.
so normally I expect my forecast(the mean model) depends only on the external regressors and their loadings

model spec
spec = ugarchspec(
  variance.model=list(garchOrder=c(1,1)),

mean.model=list(armaOrder =c(0,0),include.mean=FALSE,external.regressors=pca_factor[-nrow(db_sel),]),
  distribution.model="std")

## fit

def.fit=ugarchfit(spec = spec, data = rets_sel[,1],solver = 'hybrid')

## fitted param

```
     GARCH Model Fit        *
```

*---------------------------------*

### Conditional Variance Dynamics

GARCH Model : sGARCH(1,1)
Mean Model  : ARFIMA(0,0,0)
Distribution    : std

### Optimal Parameters

```
    Estimate  Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)
```

mxreg1 -0.000079    0.000068  -1.154394  0.24834
mxreg2  0.000205    0.000210   0.975847  0.32914
mxreg3  0.000504    0.000514   0.980258  0.32696
omega   0.000000    0.000001   0.000000  1.00000
alpha1  0.000046    0.001816   0.025302  0.97981
beta1   0.998771    0.002060 484.876499  0.00000
shape  21.454153   31.537211   0.680281  0.49633

Robust Standard Errors:
        Estimate  Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)
mxreg1 -0.000079    0.000067  -1.169832  0.24207
mxreg2  0.000205    0.000276   0.744341  0.45667
mxreg3  0.000504    0.000560   0.898923  0.36869
omega   0.000000    0.000006   0.000000  1.00000
alpha1  0.000046    0.000666   0.068985  0.94500
beta1   0.998771    0.001158 862.159146  0.00000
shape  21.454153   55.198058   0.388676  0.69752

**but here I got a value of 0 for the mean model forecast**

## forecast

ugarchforecast(def.fit, n.ahead = 1,external.forecasts =list(-6,-2.3,3.2))

*------------------------------------*
*       GARCH Model Forecast         *
*------------------------------------*
Model: sGARCH
Horizon: 1
Roll Steps: 0
Out of Sample: 0

0-roll forecast [T0=2012-11-02]:
    Series    Sigma
T+1      0 0.007263

I think , this external.forecasts =list(-6,-2.3,3.2) is not working  as it should ?

does anyone know the proper way to do this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  By default, the fitting algorithm within ugarchfit has a non-negativity constraint This makes sense when estimating the standard coefficients for a GARCH model, but not when you're using external regressors.

So you need to reset the bounds on the spec object to allow negative values. Keep in mind that this is not just the bound on the *final* coefficient, but it is the bound on the value of the coefficient at any point during the solving routine. So even if your coefficient is likely positive by the end of the solving routine, you still need to give the solver freedom to operate.

```
rugarch::setbounds(model.spec,list("vxreg1" = c(-2,2)))
```

This will allow the coefficient for your first column in your external regressor data (`vxreg1`) to take on values from -2 to 2 at any point during the routine.